# Cannot show the ReferenceField in React-admin (GraphQL, Mongoose, Apollo-server)

Tags: node.js, mongoose, graphql, apollo, react-admin

I'm new here and a beginner

I am trying to set up a stack using graphql mongoose and react-admin, after some digging i managed to have all the backend and frontend working together with apollo.

In a User / Message model type of relationship, I have noticed (from various tutorials) that sometimes the mongoose model for  the Message is defined with a `type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,` and sometimes as a `String`. I think the ObjectId would make more sense...

Moving onto the Gql schema and resolvers, it would mean that I declare in my typeDef as such

```
type Message {
  id: ID!
  text: String
  createdAt: String
  createdBy: User <- and not String?
}

type User {
  id: ID!
  username: String
  email: String
  password: String
  token: String
}
```

but so far it has not work this way, doing so results in backend error

`Error: The type of MessageInput.username must be Input Type but got: User`

and I had to go back using String, which means that the front end shows the user id and cannot show the user's name

any idea how i can solve this issue?

thanks a lot

my repo is here: https://github.com/zovitch/ra-apollo-gql-mongoose.git

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the MongoDB side of things, but if your `createdBy` foreign key is a string, react-admin will be able to display the message author just fine using `<ReferenceField>`:

```
const MessageList = () => (
  <List>
    <Datagrid>
       <TextField source="text" />
       <DateField source="createdAt" />
       <ReferenceField source="createdBy" reference="users" />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);
```

More details at https://marmelab.com/react-admin/ReferenceField.html

In the `<Admin>`, don't forget to define the default `recordRepresentation` for the users `Resource` to let react-admin know to render a user with its username:

```
<Resource name="users" recordRepresentation="username" />
```

More details at https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Resource.html#recordrepresentation

Comment: Hello and thanks for helping me, I have tried to use the ReferenceField with and without the recordRepresentation without success. I have also tried with a child component for <ReferenceField>

Does react-admin can display the message author so long as the createdBy String is the id of the User ? or it needs to be resolved in the backend ?

Comment: in a similar fashion I have tried to create a Message and used

  <ReferenceInput
          source='createdBy'
          reference='User'
        >
          <SelectInput optionText='username' />
  </ReferenceInput>

the dropdown menu seems to display the name of the author properly, but i guess an error: "Response not successful: Received status code 400"